# I'm having an issue reading onnx file using 'net = cv2.dnn.readNet("yolov7.onnx")'. how to solve this issue

Tags: python, opencv, object-detection, yolo

This is the error I am getting. I was trying to implement yolov7 object detection code using this repo - https://github.com/WongKinYiu/yolov7

And I got the yolov7.pt weight file, which is pre trained model.

And converted .pt into .onnx using this https://github.com/WongKinYiu/yolov7/blob/u5/export.py

After that I used object detection code with input as .onnx weight file.

```
import os, time
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

coco_classes = ['person', 'bicycle', 'car', 'motorcycle', 'airplane', 'bus', 'train', 'truck', 'boat', 'traffic light',
        'fire hydrant', 'stop sign', 'parking meter', 'bench', 'bird', 'cat', 'dog', 'horse', 'sheep', 'cow',
        'elephant', 'bear', 'zebra', 'giraffe', 'backpack', 'umbrella', 'handbag', 'tie', 'suitcase', 'frisbee',
        'skis', 'snowboard', 'sports ball', 'kite', 'baseball bat', 'baseball glove', 'skateboard', 'surfboard',
        'tennis racket', 'bottle', 'wine glass', 'cup', 'fork', 'knife', 'spoon', 'bowl', 'banana', 'apple',
        'sandwich', 'orange', 'broccoli', 'carrot', 'hot dog', 'pizza', 'donut', 'cake', 'chair', 'couch',
        'potted plant', 'bed', 'dining table', 'toilet', 'tv', 'laptop', 'mouse', 'remote', 'keyboard', 'cell phone',
        'microwave', 'oven', 'toaster', 'sink', 'refrigerator', 'book', 'clock', 'vase', 'scissors', 'teddy bear',
        'hair drier', 'toothbrush']

# net = cv2.dnn.readNet("yolov7.onnx")
net = cv2.dnn.readNet("/content/1-yolov7.onnx")
model = cv2.dnn_DetectionModel(net)
model.setInputParams(size=(416, 416), scale=1 / 255, swapRB=True)

path = './testimg/'

for fn in os.listdir(path):
    image = cv2.imread(path + fn)

    t = time.time()
    c, v, b = model.detect(image, 0.2, 0.4)
    t = time.time() - t

    c = [coco_classes[x] for x in c]

    for (classid, score, box) in zip(c, v, b):
        if classid == 0 or classid == 2:
            lx, ly, cw, ch = box
        x=cv2.rectangle(image, box, (255, 0, 255), 3)
    plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(x, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
    plt.waitforbuttonpress()
```

I used google Collab. it has OpenCV 4.6.0, pytorch version was 1.12, I tried using pytorch 1.11 also but it didn't solve the issue

ERROR--

```
    yolov7_detector = YOLOv7(args.modelpath, conf_thres=args.confThreshold, iou_thres=args.nmsThreshold)
  File "F:/REPO/code/yolov7-u5/detect.py", line 13, in __init__
    self.net = cv2.dnn.readNet(path)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.6.0) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\dnn\src\onnx\onnx_importer.cpp:255: error: (-5:Bad argument) Can't read ONNX file: models/yolov7_640x640.onnx in function 'cv::dnn::dnn4_v20220524::ONNXImporter::ONNXImporter'
```

instead of sharing some random solved question URL can someone kindly guide me exactly what I should do. I am very new to this and been googling for two days to solve this error [yolov5 had same issue but that solution was to change torch version to 1.11 which I tried and didn't work for me] NOTE - i am using yolov7

Comment: please have a look at [this corresponding issue](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/22215)

Comment: @berak so it's not solved yet.

Comment: no, not solved yet., WIP. we'll wait for the pr to get merged, and try again, no ?

Comment: @berak yes let's wait. Kindly reply here once you get anything.

Answer (score 0):

here is a sample solution that may help you

in the below code, I'm detecting a person in images by loading the yolov7 pre-trained model

```
import torch
import os
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import glob

# Load fine-tuned custom model
model = torch.hub.load('WongKinYiu/yolov7', 'custom', 'model_path/yolov7.pt',
                        force_reload=True, trust_repo=True)


PERSON_CONFIDENCE = 0.50
OUTPUT_DIR = 'output'

image_path_ = glob.glob('person_det_results/input_videos/all_in_one/frames/*')
out_path = 'person_det_results/input_videos/all_in_one/all_in_one_person_imgs'

os.makedirs(OUTPUT_DIR, exist_ok=True)
c = 1
# Run the Inference and draw predicted bboxes
for image_path in image_path_:
    results = model(image_path)
    df = results.pandas().xyxy[0]
    image = cv2.imread(image_path)
    for i, row in df.iterrows():
        if row['class'] == 0 and row['confidence'] > PERSON_CONFIDENCE:
            person_bbox = [int(row['xmin']), int(row['ymin']), int(row['xmax']), int(row['ymax'])]
            person_image = image[person_bbox[1]:person_bbox[3], person_bbox[0]:person_bbox[2]]
            cv2.imwrite(f'{out_path}/{c}_person.jpg', person_image)
            c+=1
            
print('Done..',c)
```

**hope it'll help**